# Java smallest rectangle enclosing others in an ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist

Given an arraylist of rectangles, my task is to find the smallest rectangle enclosing all the other rectangles.

```
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Homework {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ArrayList<Rectangle> test = new ArrayList<Rectangle>();
    test.add(new Rectangle(10, 20, 30, 40));
    test.add(new Rectangle(20, 10, 30, 40));
    test.add(new Rectangle(10, 20, 40, 50));
    test.add(new Rectangle(20, 10, 50, 30));
    Rectangle enc = enclosing(test);
    System.out.println(enc);
    System.out.println("Expected: java.awt.Rectangle[x=10,y=10,width=60,height=60]");
}

public static Rectangle enclosing(ArrayList<Rectangle> rects) {
    // Your work here
}
}
```

What I have so far:

```
public static Rectangle enclosing(ArrayList<Rectangle> rects) {
    double topLeftX = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    double topLeftY = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    double bottomRightX = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    double bottomRightY = Integer.MIN_VALUE;

    for (Rectangle r : rects) {
        if (r.getX() < topLeftX)
            topLeftX = r.getX();

        if (r.getY() < topLeftY)
            topLeftY = r.getY();

        if ((r.getX() + r.getWidth()) > bottomRightX)
            bottomRightX = (r.getX() + r.getWidth());

        if ((r.getY() + r.getHeight()) > bottomRightY)
            bottomRightY = (r.getY() + r.getHeight());
    }
    Rectangle.Double enc = new Rectangle.Double(topLeftX, topLeftY, bottomRightX - topLeftX, bottomRightY - topLeftY);

    return enc;
}
```

I get an "incompatible types" error for my return line. I'm not sure what goes there to make the output match the tester block at the top.

Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: For future reference, please use the homework tag when appropriate :)

Comment: Why are you returning a Rectangle.Double instead of a Rectangle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
Rectangle.Double enc = new Rectangle.Double(topLeftX, topLeftY, bottomRightX - topLeftX, bottomRightY - topLeftY);
```

to

```
Rectangle enc = new Rectangle((int) topLeftX, (int) topLeftY, (int) (bottomRightX - topLeftX), (int) (bottomRightY - topLeftY));
```

Comment: There doesn't seem to be a compelling reason to use doubles at all, even as an intermediate data type.  Just use ints.

Answer (score 1):

What's going on here is you've got two different types of Rectangles. You've got the normal Rectangle, which contains integer information, and Rectangle.Double, which contains doubles. Since the return type is Rectangle (the integer variation), returning a Rectangle.Double is inconsistent. Since you know that all of the rectangles in the array are integer precision,  use a Rectangle, rather than a Rectangle.Double for the result value.

Comment: It's a really brutal type hierarchy!